# Minimum vertex cover

Tags: algorithm, vertex-cover

I am trying to get a vertex cover for an "almost" tree with 50,000 vertices. The graph is generated as a tree with random edges added in making it "almost" a tree.

I used the approximation method where you marry two vertices, add them to the cover and remove them from the graph, then move on to another set of vertices. After that I tried to reduce the number of vertices by removing the vertices that have all of their neighbors inside the vertex cover.

My question is how would I make the vertex cover even smaller? I'm trying to go as low as I can.

Comment: It all hinges on: How many random edges?  We know there are exactly 49999 tree edges, but an algorithm that's practical for 20 random edges won't be for 1000000.

Comment: I don't have the exact number, but about 1/3 of the edges are extra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea, but I have no idea if it is an improvement in practice:

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component "Any connected graph decomposes into a tree of biconnected components called the block-cut tree of the graph." Furthermore, you can compute such a decomposition in linear time.

I suggest that when you marry and remove two vertices you do this only for two vertices within the same biconnected component. When you have run out of vertices to merge you will have a set of trees not connected with each other. The vertex cover problem on trees is tractable via dynamic programming: for each node compute the cost of the best answer if that node is added to the cover and if that node is not added to the cover. You can compute the answers for a node given the best answers for its children.

Another way - for all I know better - would be to compute the minimum spanning tree of the graph and to use dynamic programming to compute the best vertex cover for that tree, neglecting the links outside the tree, remove the covered links from the graph, and then continue by marrying vertices as before.

I think I prefer the minimum spanning tree one. In producing the minimum spanning tree you are deleting a small number of links. A tree with N nodes had N-1 links, so even if you don't get back the original tree you get back one with as many links as it. A vertex cover for the complete graph is also a vertex cover for the minimum spanning tree so if the correct answer for the full graph has V vertices there is an answer for the minimum spanning tree with at most V vertices. If there were k random edges added to the tree there are k edges (not necessarily the same) that need to be added to turn the minimum spanning tree into the full graph. You can certainly make sure these new edges are covered with at most k vertices. So if the optimum answer has V vertices you will obtain an answer with at most V+k vertices.

Comment: I was actually able to get down quite a bit by doing something else. Instead of using the marriage approximation, I was looking for the leaves and I would remove the neighbor of those leaves. Then after there are no leaves left, I would look for the vertex with the highest degree and remove it. Since removing a vertex also removes all the edges that are coming out of it, I would just keep doing that until every vertex in the graph has degree of 0. But thank you for your suggestion. I'll try to implement it to see if I can get even lower!

Comment: @Ccyan: Choosing neighbours of leaves is a well-known and effective optimality-preserving reduction.  There are several others, for example the Crown reduction, that are well known in the field of Fixed Parameter Tractability (where Vertex Cover is one of the most well-studied problems) -- check the literature there for more.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at an exact answer which is tractable when only a small number of links are added, or when they don't change the inter-node distances very much.

Find a minimum spanning tree, and divide edges into "tree edges" and "added edges", where the tree edges form a minimum spanning tree, and the added edges were not chosen for this. They may not be the edges actually added during construction but that doesn't matter. All trees on N nodes have N-1 edges so we have the same number of added edges as were used during creation, even if not the same edges.

Now pretend you can peek at the answer in the back of the book just enough to see, for one vertex from each added edge, whether that vertex was part of the best vertex cover. If it was, you can remove that vertex and its links from the problem. If not, the other vertex must be so you can remove it and its links from the problem.

You now have to find a minimum vertex cover for a tree or a number of disconnected trees, and we know how to do this - see my other answer for a bit more handwaving.

If you can't peek at the back of the book for an answer, and there are k added edges, try all 2^k possible answers that might have been in the back of the book and find the best. If you are lucky then added link A is in a different subtree from added link B. In that case you can confine the two calculations needed for the two possibilities for added link A (or B) to the dynamic programming calculations for the relevant subtree so you have only doubled the work instead of quadrupled it. In general, if your k added edges are in k different subtrees that don't interfere with each other, the cost is multiplied by 2 instead of 2^k.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum vertex cover is an NP complete algorithm, which means that you can not solve it in a reasonable time even for something like 100 vertices (not to mention 50k).

For a tree there is a polynomial time greedy algorithm which is based on DFS, but the fact that you have "random edges added" screws everything up and makes this algorithm useless.

[Wikipedia has an article about approximation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Approximate_evaluation), claims that it reaches factor 2 and claims that no better algorithm is know, which makes it quit unlikely that you will find one.

Comment: I believe you can do better for the special case when the graph is a tree plus a small number of added edges. This does not attempt to produce a better approximation for the general case. I have edited my answer to provide an upper bound to the cost of this idea.

Comment: I am doing the approximation and was just wondering if there's a good way to reduce it even further.

Comment: @mcdowella may be it is possible to do this if you have tiny number of extra edges (1-2) in a thousand, but in OPs case it is 1/3 of extra edges, which in my opinion is too much